# nuxt, once landing on the page, sometimes fetch hook doesn't call the api instead I get cached data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a page let's call it `pageA` in my nuxt app whose fetch hook call my vuex action that calls an api:

```
// pageA
//template
<componentA />

//script, fetch hook on pageA
    try {
      await store.dispatch("myList");
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        message: "error"
      });
    }
```

```
// my store
export const state = () => ({
  listItems: null,
});

export const actions = {
  async myList({ commit }) {
    await axios
      .get(
        `${url}`,
        {
          headers: {
            ["key"]: "abcd123"
          }
        }
      )
      .then(data => {
        if(data && data.status === 200){
          let results = data.data
          list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
          commit("SET_LIST", list);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
}
SET_LIST(state, list) {
  state.listItems = list;
},
```

And then I get the `listItem` from store state on my `<componentA>` that I import in my pageA:

```
//this is componentA:
//template 

<div v-for="lists in list" :key="list.id"
<componentB
  :name="lists.name"
  :color="lists.color"
  // and so on
></componentB>

//script
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["list"])
  }
```

The `myList` api that I call from `pageA` fetch hook api works most of the time but the issue is that sometimes it is not getting called on page load (or going back to the page) so sometimes it doesn't work. For comparison, I call another API in `componentB` fetch hook with same architecture (through store) and that one works everytime on page load. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally due to `fetch` caching mechanism and timestamp, I decided to use asyncData in this situation or use another method like `refresh` and call `this.$fetch` on it.